# pywinauto to get button where button_title and auto_id are duplicates

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to automate my task with OneStream Application.

with the 'print_control_identifiers()' command, I was able to get the identifiers.

However, when I try to simply use 
`os.child_window(title="button", auto_id="button", control_type="Button").click_input()`,
it result in an error as there's duplicates in the 'title' and 'auto_id' name.

Below are my python code and the result of the identifiers.

```
from pywinauto import application
from pywinauto.application import Application

# add your exe name here; you can get via Task Manager
exeOneStreamName = "OneStreamDesktop.exe"

# get PID of your running process
pid = application.process_from_module(module = exeOneStreamName)

# use Pid to connect
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(process = pid)

os = app.window(title_re='OneStream*')

# maximize OneStream Window. This also acts as activating OneStream window
os.wrapper_object().maximize()

#this is the part that's not working
os.child_window(auto_id="toolbarScrollViewer", control_type="Pane")['WorkspaceCustom']['WorkspaceCustom2']['Pane2']['WorkspaceCustom3']['WorkspaceCustom4']['Pane3']['Custom79']['Custom80']['Custom83']['Custom84'].child_window(title="button", auto_id="button", control_type="Button").click_input()
```

os.print_control_identifiers() output

```
   |    |    |    | Pane - ''    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
   |    |    |    | ['Pane', 'Pane0', 'Pane1']
   |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="toolbarScrollViewer", control_type="Pane")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L310, T126, R1914, B996)
   |    |    |    | ['WorkspaceCustom', 'Custom55', 'WorkspaceCustom0', 'WorkspaceCustom1']
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L310, T126, R1914, B996)
   |    |    |    |    | ['WorkspaceCustom2', 'Custom56']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="dashboardWrapper", control_type="Custom")
   |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    | Pane - ''    (L311, T127, R1913, B995)
   |    |    |    |    |    | ['Pane2', 'WorkspacePane', 'WorkspacePane0', 'WorkspacePane1']
   |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="dashboardScrollViewer", control_type="Pane")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L311, T127, R1913, B192)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['WorkspaceCustom3', 'Custom57']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L311, T127, R1913, B192)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['WorkspaceCustom4', 'Custom58']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Pane - ''    (L311, T127, R1913, B192)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Pane3', 'WorkspacePane2']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="scrollViewer", control_type="Pane")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L311, T127, R594, B192)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['WorkspaceCustom5', 'Custom59']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L311, T127, R594, B192)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['WorkspaceCustom6', 'Custom60']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Static - 'PROJECT INITIATION'    (L321, T139, R594, B179)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['PROJECT INITIATION', 'Static48', 'PROJECT INITIATIONStatic']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="PROJECT INITIATION", auto_id="textBlock", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L594, T127, R670, B192)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom61', 'PROJECT INITIATIONCustom', 'PROJECT INITIATIONCustom0', 'PROJECT INITIATIONCustom1']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L594, T127, R670, B192)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom62', 'PROJECT INITIATIONCustom2']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Pane - ''    (L619, T134, R670, B192)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Pane4', 'Division : Pane']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="scrollViewer", control_type="Pane")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L619, T134, R670, B160)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom63', 'Division : Custom', 'Division : Custom0', 'Division : Custom1']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L619, T134, R670, B160)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom64', 'Division : Custom2']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Static - 'Division : '    (L619, T134, R670, B150)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Static49', 'Division : Static', 'Division : ']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Division : ", auto_id="textBlock", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L619, T160, R670, B178)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom65', 'Division : Custom3']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L619, T160, R670, B178)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom66', 'Division : Custom4']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Static - 'OTT'    (L619, T160, R643, B178)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Static50', 'OTT', 'OTTStatic', 'OTT0', 'OTT1', 'OTTStatic0', 'OTTStatic1']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="OTT", auto_id="textBlock", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L670, T127, R845, B192)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom67', 'Division : Custom5', 'OTTCustom', 'OTTCustom0', 'OTTCustom1']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L670, T127, R845, B192)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom68', 'Division : Custom6']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Pane - ''    (L695, T134, R845, B192)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Pane5', 'Project Group : Pane']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="scrollViewer", control_type="Pane")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L695, T134, R845, B160)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom69', 'Project Group : Custom', 'Project Group : Custom0', 'Project Group : Custom1']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L695, T134, R845, B160)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom70', 'Project Group : Custom2']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Static - 'Project Group : '    (L695, T134, R777, B150)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Static51', 'Project Group : ', 'Project Group : Static']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Project Group : ", auto_id="textBlock", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L695, T160, R845, B185)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom71', 'Project Group : Custom3']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L695, T160, R845, B185)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom72', 'Project Group : Custom4']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ComboBox - ''    (L695, T160, R845, B183)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['ComboBoxActive', 'ComboBox', 'ComboBoxCancelled', 'Project Group : ComboBox', 'ComboBox0', 'ComboBox1']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="comboBox", control_type="ComboBox")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L845, T127, R1065, B192)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom73', 'Current Project : Custom', 'Current Project : Custom0', 'Current Project : Custom1']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L845, T127, R1065, B192)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom74', 'Current Project : Custom2']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Pane - ''    (L870, T134, R1065, B192)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Pane6', 'Current Project : Pane']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="scrollViewer", control_type="Pane")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L870, T134, R1065, B160)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom75', 'Current Project : Custom3']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L870, T134, R1065, B160)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom76', 'Current Project : Custom4']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Static - 'Current Project : '    (L870, T134, R959, B150)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Static52', 'Current Project : Static', 'Current Project : ']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Current Project : ", auto_id="textBlock", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L870, T160, R1065, B178)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom77', 'Current Project : Custom5']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L870, T160, R1065, B178)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom78', 'Current Project : Custom6']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Static - 'Mattamy (Oxford Village) Limited'    (L870, T160, R1065, B178)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Static53', 'Mattamy (Oxford Village) Limited', 'Mattamy (Oxford Village) LimitedStatic', 'Mattamy (Oxford Village) Limited0', 'Mattamy (Oxford Village) Limited1', 'Mattamy (Oxford Village) LimitedStatic0', 'Mattamy (Oxford Village) LimitedStatic1']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Mattamy (Oxford Village) Limited", auto_id="textBlock", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L1065, T127, R1130, B192)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom79', 'Mattamy (Oxford Village) LimitedCustom', 'Mattamy (Oxford Village) LimitedCustom0', 'Mattamy (Oxford Village) LimitedCustom1']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L1065, T127, R1130, B192)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom80', 'Mattamy (Oxford Village) LimitedCustom2']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Pane - ''    (L1090, T134, R1130, B192)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Pane7', 'Apply : Pane']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="scrollViewer", control_type="Pane")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L1090, T134, R1130, B160)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom81', 'Apply : Custom', 'Apply : Custom0', 'Apply : Custom1']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L1090, T134, R1130, B160)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom82', 'Apply : Custom2']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Static - 'Apply : '    (L1090, T134, R1130, B150)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Apply : Static', 'Static54', 'Apply : ']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Apply : ", auto_id="textBlock", control_type="Text")    
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L1090, T160, R1130, B187)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom83', 'Apply : Custom3']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L1090, T160, R1130, B187)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom84', 'Apply : Custom4']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Button - 'button'    (L1090, T160, R1121, B187)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['button', 'buttonButton', 'Button59', 'button0', 'button1', 'buttonButton0', 'buttonButton1']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="button", auto_id="button", control_type="Button")
```

Comment: Please check if `Inspect.exe` also shows the same `Name` and `AutomationId` properties in "UI Automation" mode selected in top toolbar combo box. If it is the same in `Inspect.exe`, the problem is on the application side.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov I use Inspect.exe as you mentioned, and there's no name in **AutomationId**. It's displayed as double quote **""**. The only differences are **BoudingRectangle**, **RuntimeId** and **ClickablePoint**. Is it possible to use either of this with pywinauto? If yes, how? Need help as I don't know how to. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, that's very interesting! Thanks for the report! Another way to disambiguate the search is using keyword argument `found_index=0`, for example. I've never seen such duplication previously. In the new branch `atspi` on GitHub we implemented `Inspect.exe` compatible mode for "uia" backend, but it is slower than the default mode. Maybe `found_index` is better solution anyway.

Comment: `BoudingRectangle` can be obtained by method `.rectangle()` for already found element wrapper. But it can't be used as a keyword argument in search criteria. The same for `RuntimeId`. Both these values may be unstable from run to run. We don't recommend using such values at all. Though `.rectangle()` is useful and used in calculation of default click point in method `.click_input()` by using `.rectangle().mid_point()`.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Thank you so much for replying and guiding me. I was able to play around yesterday and was finally able to click on the 'Apply' icon that I want by using the code ```os['Custom84'].child_window(title="button", auto_id="button", control_type="Button")```. However it took close to 1 minute before it click which to me is unacceptably slow. I was also googling and tried to use the ```mouse.move(x.y)``` coordinate. However, I can't use that because the pane of that 'Apply' image coordinate is not static but dynamic.

Comment: Most probably search of `os['Custom84']` is slow. I'd suggest `os.child_window(auto_id="scrollViewer", control_type="Pane").child_window(title="button", control_type="Button")`. And yes, the dynamism of many things makes GUI automation so complicated area. :)

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Thank you Vasily again for trying to teach and help me out. I tried your solution, but it threw me an error ```pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'auto_id': 'scrollViewer', 'control_type': 'Pane', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': <uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo - 'OneStream XF', Window, 132870>, 'backend': 'uia'}``` The reason being is that ```child_window(auto_id="scrollViewer", control_type="Pane")``` has 54 matches when I'm looking at the "hierarchy" from ```print_control_identifiers()``` output

Comment: OK, maybe skipping some level of hierarchy makes sense with combination of `found_index` keyword in the search criteria. Something like this: `os.child_window(title="button", control_type="Button", found_index=13).draw_outline()`. The method `draw_outline()` helps to identify visually that the right element is found. `found_index` is zero-based. This is the last bastion of a search disambiguation. :)

Comment: @VasilyRyabov if I may ask, how do you determine ```13``` in ```found_index=13```? I shall try it out and see how it goes. Thank you once again for your help.

Comment: It is just a random number for example. :) Or maybe some approximation based on incomplete output. :) Anyway, if you find the right code, please post it as an answer and mark it as accepted to improve statistics on tag `pywinauto`. Thanks! :)

Comment: @VasilyRyabov tried your method using found_index but return error.  ```Traceback (most recent call last):
    os.child_window(title="button", control_type="Button", found_index=13).click_input()
  ... ... ...
  File "C:\Users\dluhu\Documents\Python Script\Atom\venvOneStream\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 328, in find_elements
    raise ElementNotFoundError("found_index is specified as {0}, but {1} window/s found".format(
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: found_index is specified as 13, but 0 window/s found``` is the code error.